# Incrementing user time variable Bash

Tags: bash, shell

In the script I'm working on the user defines a variable labeled start time. I would like to increment and decrement that variable by ±3 hrs. The format is 00:00:00 (24hr) and I'm uncertain if there is a better way that doesn't involve string manipulation because if it is less than zero I can't pass -03:00:00 to the Python script that utilizes this variable.

```
#somescript.sh 00:01:35    
STARTTIME=$1
E=${STARTTIME%*:}
S=${STARTTIME##*:} && ((S=S+3)
echo "$S : $E"
```

Desired Result: 03:01:35 and 21:01:35

Reviewed: [String Operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) and [Incrementing time (minutes and seconds) in bash / shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991854/incrementing-time-minutes-and-seconds-in-bash-shell-script) prior to asking this question. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The second question you supposedly reviewed has answers showing how to use GNU date to do date math, which is the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't have linked it if I didn't review it. There is a date component elsewhere in the script that is not included in the question that I was concerned would cause a issue with my date. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are reserved for shell builtin variables and environment variables. See the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to see how code elsewhere in your script could interfere with `date -d`, unless you're modifying environment variables associated with timezones. Anyhow, if there's a restriction that impacts the range of possible answers, include it!

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification @CharlesDuffy, I wasn't aware thus the question. Still learning; really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
starttime=$1
endtime=$(date -u -d "$starttime 3 hours" +'%H:%M:%S')
echo "${starttime} - $endtime"
```

...used as:

```
$ ./add-time 01:01:35
01:01:35 - 04:01:35
```

If you need to go in the opposite direction, add the word "ago":

```
endtime=$(date -u -d "$starttime 3 hours ago" +'%H:%M:%S')
```